# Doctrine2 update only using objects

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to make update with criteria in Doctrine2 without using DQL and Native SQL? I mean only working with objects.

For example something like this:

```
$data = new Entities\Articles();
$data->setStatus("published");

/*
  Add some criteria for update here 
*/

$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();
```

What I want to do: Update multiple records without loading them from database.

Comment: This code will create an insert not an update statement. You can load the entities with your criteria update and flush them. What kind of criteria are you looking for?

Comment: @flec I know that it will insert. Criteria can be anything for example `WHERE id > 10`. I forgot to mention it in the question (will update it) but the main thing I want is to update multiple records without loading them from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Doctrine ORM does not currently support using the criteria API for updates. Criteria API is currently only available to fetch data, and still at a very early state.

If you can help us improve it, that would be awesome :)

The only currently available ways are through [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries) and NativeSQL

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So there is no way, only using objects, to update multiple records in the database without loading them before from database?

Comment: @JurisVaiders You could use the queryBuilder (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html) if you prefere the object syntax.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. Thanks.